# Using Update Query to Copy Column Data

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need to copy the value in a column named TEAM from one row into another row. Both rows need to have the same team name. This is my query that doesn't work:

```
$query = "UPDATE profiles SET team = (SELECT team FROM profiles WHERE id = '$coach_id') WHERE id = '$player_id'";
```

I have tried removing single quotes, removing "FROM profiles", changing value to table.value, tried to give a newdata.clan alias, and I have even tried changing the values to integers instead of parameters. Nothing works, and this is what I get:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE id = '') WHERE id = ''' at
>   line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query1 = "SELECT team FROM profiles WHERE id = '$coach_id'";

/* get the value of the first query and assign it to a variable like $team_name */

$query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET team = '$team_name' WHERE id = '$player_id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you should surround your PHP variables in curly braces:

```
$query = "UPDATE profiles SET team = \"(SELECT team FROM profiles WHERE id = '{$coach_id}')\" WHERE id = '{$player_id}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL manual:

> "Currently, you cannot update a table
>   and select from the same table in a
>   subquery."

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Use the method that FinalForm wrote:

```
<?
$coach_id = 2;
$player_id = 1;

$query1 = "SELECT team FROM profiles WHERE id = '$coach_id'";
$rs = mysql_query($query1);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $team_name = $row['team'];
  $query2 = "UPDATE profiles SET team = '$team_name' WHERE id = '$player_id'";
  mysql_query($query2);
  // Done, updated if there is an id = 1
} else {
  // No id with id = 2
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to run two queries just like FinalForm wrote. I'm writing a complete code now so you'll see.

Comment: Thank FinalForm, he was the one who wrote it first, I just entered the steps between to clarify. Accept his answer as the correct one.

Comment: No you can only choose one, remove mine and add FinalForms :)

Comment: I'm on it..creating an account! Then the point is yours when I get my 15 rep points (: